# Image not retrieving from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am trying to build a messenger type app. And for this, I have uploaded an image from my phone to Firebase. The image is successfully stored in Firebase storage. I am trying to show the image on my phone. And I use both Picasso and Glide to retrieve the image from Firebase. But my picture isn't showing. But when I add placeholder I can see the default image that is set by a placeholder. How can I solve this problem? My code is given below:

```
package com.example.ichat;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button UpdateAccountSetting;
    private EditText userName, userStatus;
    private CircleImageView userProfileImage;
    private String currentUserId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference RootRef;
    private static final int GalleryPick = 1;
    private StorageReference UserProfileImagesRef;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        UserProfileImagesRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

        InitializeFields();

        UpdateAccountSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UpdateSettings();
            }
        });

        RetrieveUserInfo();

        userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GalleryPick);
            }
        });
    }

    private void RetrieveUserInfo() {
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))){
                    String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                    userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                    userStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                    Glide.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(retrieveProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(userProfileImage);
                    //Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);
                    //Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).resize(100,100).centerCrop().into(userProfileImage);
                }
                else if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name"))){
                    String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                    userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                    userStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                }
                else {
                    userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please set & update your profile information...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        /*
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))){
                    String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                    userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                    userStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                    Glide.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(retrieveProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(userProfileImage);
                    //Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);
                    //Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).resize(100,100).centerCrop().into(userProfileImage);
                }
                else if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name"))){
                    String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                    userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                    userStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                }
                else {
                    userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please set & update your profile information...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });*/
    }

    private void UpdateSettings() {
        String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
        String setStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName)) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your user name first....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setStatus)) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your status....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, Object> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
            profileMap.put("uid", currentUserId);
            profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
            profileMap.put("status", setStatus);
            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).updateChildren(profileMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profile Updated Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        String message = task.getException().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error : "+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void InitializeFields() {
        UpdateAccountSetting = findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
        userStatus =findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
        userProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(data != null){
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
            loadingBar.setTitle("Set Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, your profile image is updating...");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingBar.show();
            StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImagesRef.child(currentUserId+".jpg");
            filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profile Image uploaded Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image save in Database Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                                else{
                                    String message = task.getException().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                }
            });
            //String downloadUrl = filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
            /*filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profile Image uploaded Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image save in Database Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                                else{
                                    String message = task.getException().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        String message = task.getException().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });*/
        }
    }
}
```

My XML File Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/settingsbackground"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/set_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_image"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/set_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/set_profile_image"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/set_profile_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/set_user_name"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Hey, I am available now"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_settings_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/set_profile_status"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="Update"
        android:background="@drawable/update_btn_style"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="28sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My gradle file code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ichat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

My Firebase Data Structure:
[My Firebase Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEb6w.png)

Comment: Please make a log and check data was correct or not then check if data correct username and userstatus displaying perfect value if not then use runOnUIthread

Comment: Username and userstatus value is perfect and retrieveProfileImage value is "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@4b1f293"

Comment: Ur inserted wrong value in userProfilePic url its now downloadeble url

Comment: What should I insert in userProfilePic? Can you tell me?

Comment: Downloadeble Url of image.... Did you uploaded image into firebase storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this line `final String downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();` ur not getting correct downloadeble url of image, so use `filePath.getDownloadUrl()`

**`Example`**

```
filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                final String downloadUrl = uri;
                        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image save in Database Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                                else{
                                    String message = task.getException().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

or use continueWithTask

```
//add file on Firebase and got Download Link
filePath.putFile(imageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            Uri downUri = task.getResult();
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Url: "+ downUri.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad to help you sir