# Make upload method return String "the uploaded file url"

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I'm uploading an image to Firebase Storage, I need the image URL in the Storage to use it then to insert it within a document in FireStore.
How to get the url after the upload process is finished and not before it finished?

```
   public String uploadImage(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            final StorageReference ref = storage.child("images/" + new Date().toString());
            ref.putBytes(bytes)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    res = uri.toString();
                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
            System.out.println("RES : " + res);
            return res;
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            return null;
        }
    }

//the variable res must return a not null value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref :: [Image not retrieving from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547642/image-not-retrieving-from-firebase/55573353#55573353)

```
//add file on Firebase and got Download Link
filePath.putFile(imageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            Uri downUri = task.getResult();
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Url: "+ downUri.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: yes exactly, but it returns null because the upload process has not finished yet

Answer (score 0):

we can get the URL of a file from `taskSnapshot`, like that:

```
public String uploadImage(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        final StorageReference ref = storage.child("images/" + new Date().toString());
        ref.putBytes(bytes)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!urlTask.isSuccessful()) ;
                        Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                    }
                });
        System.out.println("RES : " + res);
        return res;
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: well thank you so much, but the problem is that the methods returns the variable res before finishing the upload process, so this method returns null.

Comment: just try now, and tell me.

Comment: Oh I see what you did there, Yes this supposed to work;
Thank you so much

Comment: logically It supposed to work fine, but didn't work, the app freezes then exit.

Comment: Ok, put the error which appears here and makes some logs in your code